# Multiple leaks on closing the swift app

Tags: ios, swift, memory-leaks

When I was working with my **Swift App** there was no leak except one for UIAlertController.
After closing the app I was shocked looking at the leaks section. 
I couldn't able to trace out from the stack. So I am really confused to share the code.

Though its my first app I was careful to avoid leaks but I really dont know where I have messed with.

I need your suggestion to overcome this issue.
[image: Leaks Instrument showing this on Exit]

Comment: Don't worry about it. A leak that appears only when you quit the app is not a leak!

Comment: @matt Fine, thanks matt. Feeling relaxed to see your comment. I ll take it in a positive way. But everything has a reason I think. Just curious to know the reason. Will figure it out some other time. Thanks again matt.

Comment: A leak is something that wasn't deallocated by your app.  If it only occurs as you're closing your app, you don't have to worry about it because the OS is going to clean up all of your app's memory anyway.

Comment: @nhgrif Got it! Thanks.